# MySQL JSON_REMOVE with multi array

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysql-json

I have the following JSON doc stored in MySQL 8 column called my_data:

```
{
  "managers": {
    "11": {
      "created": "2019-11-07"
    },
    "12": {
      "created": "2020-03-12"
    },
  }
}
```

How can I remove the "11" info.

```
UPDATE table SET my_data = JSON_REMOVE(my_data, ??) WHERE id = 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the data you show is not valid JSON. I think it should be the following:

```
{
  "managers": {
    "11": {
      "created": "2019-11-07"
    },
    "12": {
      "created": "2020-03-12"
    }
  }
}
```

I set a variable so I could test with it:

```
mysql> set @j = '...json above...';
```

I tried this, but it didn't like using an integer as a path key:

```
mysql> select json_remove(@j, '$.managers.11');
ERROR 3143 (42000): Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 13.
```

So I quoted the key as `"11"`:

```
mysql> select json_remove(@j, '$.managers."11"');
+-------------------------------------------------+
| json_remove(@j, '$.managers."11"')              |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| {"managers": {"12": {"created": "2020-03-12"}}} |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

---

But I would really do it this way:

```
DELETE FROM managers WHERE manager_id = 11;
```

That is, don't use JSON at all. Create a table for `managers`, with the 11 or 12 values as the primary key.

Using JSON in MySQL just makes it much harder to write code, and less efficient. This is what the [Inner-Platform Effect antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect) is all about.